# ClassNotFoundException in Domino 9

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Domino 9.0.1 
ExtLib: 9.0.1 v 4_20140226_1506
ODA: 1.5.0.201406241744

**Current Situation**
I develop my applications on a local server.  I use a great deal of java along with both the extension libraries and the openNTF Domino API.  My java classes are created in the perspective view in a Web Content/Web-INF/src folder.  When I am ready for deployment, I create a template and convert the src files into a jar, and copy it into a Web Content/Web-INF/lib folder and add them to the build path while removing and deleting the src folder from build path and application respectively.  I have found this to be a much more stable approach.

My templates from multiple applications run without issues on my local servers. Up until a week ago, these applications were also running without issue on a customer server. At some point, something on the server has changed and multiple applications are no longer running.  I am getting the following Messages (some text is darkened out to protect the customer):
[image]

And the following stack trace:

```
com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
    com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:132)
    javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:123)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UISelectItemsEx.getValue(UISelectItemsEx.java:64)
    com.sun.faces.util.Util.getSelectItems(Util.java:492)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getOptionNumber(MenuRenderer.java:410)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:388)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:357)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:47)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeEnd(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:180)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:1005)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UISelectOneEx.encodeEnd(UISelectOneEx.java:331)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:858)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:651)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:321)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:261)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    org.openntf.domino.xsp.adapter.OpenntfHttpService.doService(OpenntfHttpService.java:89)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.faces.FacesException: Can't instantiate class: 'de.holistic.XXXX.searchEngine.SUDValuesManager'.. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createAndMaybeStoreManagedBeans(ApplicationAssociate.java:278)
    com.sun.faces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:135)
    com.ibm.xsp.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:71)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.ServerSideLocalObject.resolveVariable(ServerSideLocalObject.java:97)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.ServerSideLocalObject.resolveAttribute(ServerSideLocalObject.java:73)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.AbstractLocalObject._get(AbstractLocalObject.java:119)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.AbstractLocalObject.getPropertyReference(AbstractLocalObject.java:101)
    com.ibm.jscript.engine.ProgramContext.findGlobalScopeIdentifier(ProgramContext.java:143)
    com.ibm.jscript.engine.ProgramContext.findIdentifier(ProgramContext.java:134)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIdentifier.interpret(ASTIdentifier.java:105)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTMember.interpret(ASTMember.java:106)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:88)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTArgumentList.interpretArguments(ASTArgumentList.java:65)
    com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:153)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:362)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:194)
    com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:78)
    javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:123)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UISelectItemsEx.getValue(UISelectItemsEx.java:64)
    com.sun.faces.util.Util.getSelectItems(Util.java:492)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getOptionNumber(MenuRenderer.java:410)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:388)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:357)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:47)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeEnd(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:180)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:1005)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UISelectOneEx.encodeEnd(UISelectOneEx.java:331)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:858)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:651)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:321)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:261)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    org.openntf.domino.xsp.adapter.OpenntfHttpService.doService(OpenntfHttpService.java:89)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
javax.faces.FacesException: Can't instantiate class: 'de.holistic.<removed for customer anonyminity>.searchEngine.SUDValuesManager'.. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    com.sun.faces.config.ManagedBeanFactory.newInstance(ManagedBeanFactory.java:234)
    com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createAndMaybeStoreManagedBeans(ApplicationAssociate.java:269)
    com.sun.faces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:135)
    com.ibm.xsp.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:71)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.ServerSideLocalObject.resolveVariable(ServerSideLocalObject.java:97)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.ServerSideLocalObject.resolveAttribute(ServerSideLocalObject.java:73)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.AbstractLocalObject._get(AbstractLocalObject.java:119)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.AbstractLocalObject.getPropertyReference(AbstractLocalObject.java:101)
    com.ibm.jscript.engine.ProgramContext.findGlobalScopeIdentifier(ProgramContext.java:143)
    com.ibm.jscript.engine.ProgramContext.findIdentifier(ProgramContext.java:134)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIdentifier.interpret(ASTIdentifier.java:105)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTMember.interpret(ASTMember.java:106)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:88)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTArgumentList.interpretArguments(ASTArgumentList.java:65)
    com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:153)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:362)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:194)
    com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:78)
    javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:123)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UISelectItemsEx.getValue(UISelectItemsEx.java:64)
    com.sun.faces.util.Util.getSelectItems(Util.java:492)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getOptionNumber(MenuRenderer.java:410)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:388)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:357)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:47)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeEnd(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:180)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:1005)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UISelectOneEx.encodeEnd(UISelectOneEx.java:331)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:858)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderChildren(FacesUtil.java:873)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_extended.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:206)
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeChildren(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:162)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:979)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:844)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
```

**Attempted Solutions**

1. All projects have been resigned and rebuilt (numerous times).
2. Notes.ini has been checked to ensure the loading of OSGi libraries.  Additionally, console commands have been executed and loading of the libraries have been confirmed.
3. Originally, the ExtLib Update site was changed in the Notes.ini. This was changed to point to the correct updateSite.nsf.
4. Test XPage applications have been created on the server using ODA, ExtLibs, and basic classes.  All Java classes could load properly, however these tests only use java classes stored in Web Content/WEB-INF/src and not jars. No issues with the test databases could be found.
5. Using the Navigator, the Web Content/WEB-INF/Classes file has been deleted manually, and the projects have been rebuilt.
6. Local content was deleted manually and the application was rebuilt.
7. The domino server security document tab was checked to confirm that the signature of the applications was listed as allowed to run java and xpages.
8. It goes without saying that the faces-config.xml file was checked to confirm proper spellings and for completeness.  No issues were found.
9. The build paths were checked to confirm that they are correctly set.  No issues were seen.

**Questions**
If it can be assumed that someone changed server settings (as the OSGI notes.ini variable was changed) what could also be changed that would cause ClassNotFound runtime exceptions?
What else can I do to solve this issue?  Again, locally, all applications are running normally.  Only on the customer's test server am I getting these runtime exceptions.

Comment: Has http been restarted? There's been another question about jar files not updating until after an HTTP restart. Also, is there any code in the constructors that could be failing and does a print statement in the constructor get loaded. The other thing to check would be any differences in Java security settings.

Comment: That has been tried multiple times, and needed to be completed once the notes.ini was corrected.

Comment: Try this: add a properties file in a folder e.g. "res/test.properties", add "res" to Java build path's source, change the properties file and build the project. We have ClassNotFoundException at runtime if we change .xsp file only. If we change a Java class or resource afterwards then it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help.  I am having the administrators take another look at the server document. Although the security tab looks fine to me, maybe they changed something else that is affecting the system. I just do not understand what affect some applications, but not all.

Comment: as Paul said, have you checked the java.policy settings? the code is running through the access controller.

Comment: also when checking bundle status through console, are they all 'resolved' or are any only 'installed'. if so you can run diag to see why it is not resolving. if this is all good I agree with Paul that checking the constructor is being called, the null pointer exception is fishy. have you double checked the .class files are actually in the jar? use 7zip to inspect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something in your Constructor of SUDValuesManager is throwing a NullPointerException. I am fairly confident this is the case... because I have just had the same Exception of the same format:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Can't instantiate class: 
<INSERT CLASS NAME HERE>.. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

NullPointerException is the real exception here, not the ClassNotFoundException.
In my case, In my constructor I was accessing a view to populate some values. I wasn't testing for null on a view that I was retrieving (hence the NullPointerException) and this then also threw the ClassNotFoundException. Because I had not yet refreshed the design of the target database, it did not have the view, and this the Null Pointer Exception when I tried to retreive a viewEntryCollection from it.

Check your code in your constructor for SUDValuesManager for any possible NPE's that you are not guarding against, or surround it in a try/catch (Exception e) and print the stack trace of any caught exceptions.

Comment: This is at the very least a problem with one of the applications in question.  I have a feeling that it is the core of the problem for the second application as well, but it is taking me some time to figure out where the exact problem is. It is funny how a ClassNotFoundException was being printed instead of the TargetInvocationException. Not the first odd ball problem that I have seen though.